# Google Spreadsheets Change from Horizontal to Vertical One Column

Tags: google-sheets

Any idea how to convert form of sheet 1 to sheet 2?

Test Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MS4VvpS03Rnd-TMWohTlAS0vhfa4JxsX1TBpqorsi7A/edit?usp=sharing

Sheet 1

```
ID        URL              Price (from-to)  
1    www.tseting.com            2-15    
2     www.hello.com             1-10
```

Sheet 2

```
[1]
url = www.tseting.com
price = 2-15

[2]
url = www.hello.com
price = 1-10
```

ANSWER:

```
=ArrayFormula(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({"[","url = ","price = ","dontsearchkeywords = "}&FILTER(Sheet1!A2:D,LEN(Sheet1!A2:A))&{"]"&CHAR(9),CHAR(9),CHAR(9),CHAR(9)&" "&CHAR(9)}),,4)),,ROWS(Sheet1!A2:D)),CHAR(9)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may start with smth like this:

`=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ArrayFormula(CONCATENATE(Sheet1!A2:E7&"@ ")),"@"))`